# Need help displaying the result of an asynchronous function on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, api, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to use the Spotify PKCE authorization with Siri Shortcuts. Unfortunately, none of the solutions I have found have been applicable to my specific situation. I have this bit of code
And I really have no idea what I am doing. Basically I need a SHA256 hash of a string of characters, but this needs to be by bytes vs the hex. This then needs to be base64Url encoded. I’ve have tried most of the solutions on stack but I can’t seem to output the final product onto a webpage, which is the main way I am able to run Java script natively on iPhone. Any help would be greatly appreciated

````
<script>

    function sha256(plain) { 
        // returns promise ArrayBuffer
        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const data = encoder.encode(plain);
        return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
    }

    function base64urlencode(a) {
        // Convert the ArrayBuffer to string using Uint8 array.
        // btoa takes chars from 0-255 and base64 encodes.
        // Then convert the base64 encoded to base64url encoded.
        // (replace + with -, replace / with _, trim trailing =)
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(a)))
            .replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
    }

    async function pkce_challenge_from_verifier(v) {
        hashed = await sha256(v);
        base64encoded = base64urlencode(hashed);
        return base64encoded;
    }

const code = await pkce_challenge_from_verifier("Zg6klgrnixQJ629GsawRMV8MjWvwRAr-vyvP1MHnB6X8WKZN")

document.getElementById("value").innerHTML =  code;

</script>
<body>

<p id="value"></p>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: js looks fine. try placing js script at the end of body after your markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` is not allowed at global level i.e you can use `await` only inside  `async` functions.
So how to solve? use promise instead of `await`. like this

```js
pkce_challenge_from_verifier("Zg6klgrnixQJ629GsawRMV8MjWvwRAr-vyvP1MHnB6X8WKZN")
  .then((code) => document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = code)
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

also place `<script> ... </script>` after `body` end tag otherwise JS cant find `p` element.